# psql: more straightforward way to exec shell command with interpolated psql variables

Tags: shell, psql

In `psql` I'd like to exec a shell command with interpolated psql variables like

```
postgres=> \! pg_dump -Fc -d :source_db | pg_restore -d :dest_db
```

But the `psql` docs make clear that this doesn't work:

> the entire remainder of the line is always taken to be the argument(s) of !, and neither variable interpolation nor backquote expansion are performed in the arguments.

I've found the following workarounds, but they feel unnecessarily cumbersome.  Is there a better way?  Maybe there are feature requests for a meta-command like `\!` that does interpolation?

Workaround 1: build command with SQL and use `\g` to pass it to `bash`

```
postgres=> SELECT 'pg_dump -Fc -d ' || :'source_db' || ' | pg_restore -d ' || :'dest_db' \g (tuples_only=on) | bash
```

Workaround 2: move values to environment variables with `\setenv`

```
postgres=> \setenv SOURCE_DB :source_db
postgres=> \setenv DEST_DB :dest_db
postgres=> \! pg_dump -Fc -d $SOURCE_DB | pg_restore -d $DEST_DB
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if there's a cleaner way to do it.  To me these ways aren't good enough and worth improving

Comment: There should be a less cumbersome syntax like `pg_dump -Fc -d :source_db | pg_restore -d :dest_db` for shell commands.  If `psql` doesn't already support doing that in any way then it would be a good feature request.  We can already interpolate psql variables in SQL statements, why no way to do so in shell commands?  Just making sure I didn't overlook some way of doing it that already exists.

Comment: I see. I don't think there is an easier way. `psql` is not primarily there to launch shell commands.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it seems quite intended for working with shell commands in addition to running SQL queries; the `\g`, `\o`, and `\w` meta-commands can all pipe to shell commands.